# How to remove single quotes in python

Tags: python

I have

```
filename = src_filename
print filename
```

somehow it is printing filename = 'apple' instead of just apple. Is there a way I can remove these single quotes.

Comment: How are you printing them?

Comment: Execute `print(filename)` in the REPL and not just `filename` as it would not give the `repr` output.

Comment: print filename. Actually I want to make use of this filename in rest of the code.

Comment: @geek_xed Can you please [edit] your post to add more context

Comment: What is `src_filename` ? where does it come from?

Comment: I have a src_itertools directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> print(filename.strip('"\''))
```

Comment: Notice that `strip` will only remove the characters in the string from both ends, and that the string argument is actually interpreted as a list of characters to remove if found. To remove only single quotes anywhere in a string, `filename = filename.replace("'", "")` and to also remove double quotes, you can chain the replacements, like `filename = filename.replace("'", "").replace('"', '')`

Comment: @tripleee Agree, I've had problems with strip many times, where replace seemed to be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes denote a string literal

```
>>> 'apple'
'apple'
```

If you `print` the string, it will not use the single quotes

```
>>> print('apple')
apple
```

So in your case you can simply

```
print(filename)
```